# Ruby on Rails 4.0 session[cart_id] = nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, session-variables

In my process of learning RoR 4.0, I am following a tutorial to build a Rails project where a Cart is being implemented. My problem is that I can't place more than one item on my cart, because when I go back to the main page to select another item, my cart changes its id . I have the cart_id stored on a session variable, on a function on my application controller:
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

private

```
def current_cart
  if session[cart_id].nil?              (*)
 puts “  ********************* “        (*)
     puts session[cart_id]              (*)
  end

  Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  cart = Cart.create
  session[:cart_id] = cart.id
  cart
end
```

end

I call this function from this controller as follows:
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController
def create
    @cart = current_cart
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @line_item = @cart.line_items.build(:product => product)

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @line_item.save
    format.html { redirect_to(@line_item.cart,
      :notice => 'Line item was successfully created.') }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @line_item,
      :status => :created, :location => @line_item }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @line_item.errors,
      :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

I made several testes, added the three lines of code marked as (*) to my current_cart and I notice that every time that @cart = currect_cart is executed on my lineItems Controller, session[cart_id] is nil.
How could this happen? can comeone explain this to me?

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: I see you have `session[:cart_id]` and `session[cart_id]` in different places. These are different things. Could it be that you've mistaken one for another?

Comment: I see what you are saying. However, the vital part to change the session is writen as session[:card_id]. It is alway getting into the rescue block of code, some how, and creating a new Cart and therefore, a new cart_id.